# Find PCI slot form factor from PCI config space

Tags: pci-e

I am working in C++ on Windows and trying to develop a tool that can identify which PCI slots are in use. I can read PCI config space to find the PCI devices that have slots and which of those slots are in use. I also need to know the form factor of the slots (CEM, M.2, U.2, Oculink). Is there anything in PCI config space that indicates the form factor of a slot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use WMI to query `Win32_SystemSlot` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-systemslot)

It contains a lot of info, but i think `LengthAllowed` is what describes slot width and probably `Model` is what you are looking for